# Use of regular expressions in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the code as below:

Please find at the end, what i am looking for.

```
string = "((apple_c >= 53.3 and ball_c == faulty) or (duster_c != 3.0))"
calibs = re.findall("\w*_c",string)
values = re.findall("\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}",string)
operators = re.findall("([!<>=]{1,2})\s*",string)
print(calibs)
print(values)
print(operators)
```

Actual output:

```
    ['apple_c', 'ball_c', 'duster_c']
    ['53.3', '3.0']
    ['>=', '==', '!=']
```

Expected output:

```
    ['apple_c', 'ball_c', 'duster_c']
    ['53.3','faulty', '3.0']
    ['>=', '==', '!=']
```

Comment: Do you know all the comparison operators that will be in your string? (e.g., `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `>=`, (any others?))? If you do, then you can simply match the value that appears directly to the right of these. What I have in mind is a pattern something like: `(!=|==|<=|>=)\s([^\s)]+)(\s|\))`. From this, you would get the values from match group 2.

Comment: Yes. it will be only these comparison operators that will be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get the values you want:

```
import re

subj = "((apple_c >= 53.3 and ball_c == faulty) or (duster_c != 3.0))"

# Get all targeted values from subj into a list
values = re.findall("(!=|==|<=|>=)\s([^\s)]+)(\s|\))", subj)
# Use list comprehension to build a list with only values of interest from matches
values_list = [a_value[1] for a_value in values]

print(values_list)
```

Outputs: ['53.3', 'faulty', '3.0']

Comment: To understand the mechanics here -- the regex looks for the known list of operators `('!=', '==', '<=', '>=')`, then a space, then the key part of the regex matches anything that _isn't_ a space or a ')' character and captures this into match group 2.

Comment: Thanks MurrayW for the inputs. This solved my problem